# How can I plot multiple v-tooltips overtop a v-img using a v-overlay?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create an image-tagging mini app using Vue and Vuetify 3. My thinking was to use `v-img` with a `v-overlay` inside a `v-container`. However, my attempt below using this approach shows the image itself, but is not showing the tooltips at all on on the dom; let alone plotting them at the appropriate spots on the image. How can I accomplish what I'm looking to do using Vuetify components?

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify;
const vuetify = createVuetify();
const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      tooltips: [{
          x: 100,
          y: 200,
          text: 'Haley'
        },
        {
          x: 200,
          y: 200,
          text: 'Francine'
        },
        // Add more tooltips as needed
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Add new tooltip on click
    addTooltip(event) {
      const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
      const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
      this.tooltips.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        text: 'New Tooltip'
      });
    },
  },
});
app.use(vuetify);
app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.4.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.21/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid>
        <!-- Image component -->
        <v-img src="https://tvseriesfinale.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/americandad40-e1679976926465-590x391.jpg" style="position: relative;" @click="addTooltip($event)">
          <!-- Tooltips overlay -->
          <v-overlay :value="true">
            <!-- Tooltips -->
            <v-tooltip v-for="(tooltip, index) in tooltips" :key="index" :text="tooltip.text" :position-x="tooltip.x" :position-y="tooltip.y" bottom>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
                <v-icon v-bind="props" color="blue" dark>mdi-tag</v-icon>
              </template>
            </v-tooltip>
          </v-overlay>
        </v-img>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using Vue/Vuetify 3, so it has to be `:model-value="true"`, not `:value="true"` in the v-overlay (I think v-overlay still closes when you click on it though). Also, there is no `:position-x/y` in v3 v-tooltip, use [`:target`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-target) instead, but I am not sure if that works when you use an activator slot. Might be easier to absolute-position the activators? Btw, the overlay and the tooltips (which have their own overlay) are inserted at the end of the body, not at the position in the template.